Show that $\frac{1+z-\sqrt{z^2-6z+1}}{4}$ fits the Lagrangean framework

Let $S(z)$ be the OGF of bracketings. Show that the Lagrangean framework holds for $S(z)$.
Remark: You can find the definition of Lagrangean framework below.

From the Flajolet & Sedgewick book (p.81) we know that for $S(z)$ holds
$$S(z) = \frac{1+z-\sqrt{z^2-6z+1}}{4} \quad  \text{ and } \quad S(z) = z + \frac{S(z)^2}{1-S(z)}.$$
and according to Wolfram Alpha the series expansion of $S(z)$ looks like this:
$$S(z) = z + z^2 + 3 z^3 + 11 z^4 + 45 z^5 + 197 z^6 + 903 z^7 + 4279 z^8 + 20793 z^9 + 103049 z^{10} + 518859 z^{11} + \mathcal{O}(z^{12}).$$
However, I do not know how to rigorously find a formula for the coefficients of $\phi(z)$ to show condition $(A)$. Could you please give me a hint?

Lagrangean Framework: We say that $f$ fulfills the Lagrangean framework if
$$f(z) = z \phi(f(z)), \qquad (A)$$
where both $\phi$ and $f$ are formal power series and if the following conditions for $\phi(z) := \sum_{j \ge 0} a_z z^j$  hold:

$\phi(0) \ne 0$
(Nonnegativity) $a_j \ge 0 \quad (j \ge 0)$,
(Aperiodicity) $gcd \{j : a_j > 0 \} = 1$;
(Analyticity) $\phi$ is analytic in $\lvert z \rvert < R, 0 < R \le \infty$;
(Sub-criticality) $r\phi^\prime(r) = \phi(r)$ for some $r \in (0,R)$


EDIT: Folllowing anon's suggestion I computed
$$\phi(z) = 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{n-1} z^n$$
Below you can find some intermediate results:
\begin{align}
S(z) &= z + z^2 + 3 z^3 + 11 z^4 + 45 z^5 + 197 z^6 + 903 z^7 + 4279 z^8 + 20793 z^9 + 103049 z^{10} + 518859 z^{11} + \mathcal{O}(z^{12}) \\
S(z)^2 &= z^2 + 2 z^3 + 7 z^4 + 28 z^5 + 121 z^6 + 550 z^7 + \mathcal{O}(z^8)\\
S(z)^3 &= z^3 + 3 z^4 + 12 z^5 + 52 z^6 + 237 z^7 + 1119 z^8 + \mathcal{O}(z^9)\\
S(z)^4 &= z^4 + 4 z^5 + 18 z^6 + 84 z^7 + 403 z^8 + 1976 z^9 + 9860 z^{10} + \mathcal{O}(z^{11}) \\
S(z)^5 &= z^5 + 5 z^6 + 25 z^7 + 125 z^8 + 630 z^9 + 3206 z^{10} + \mathcal{O}(z^{11})
\end{align}
However, I do not see how to formally prove the identity
$$S(z) = z \phi(S(z))$$
Could you please give me a hint?

One reasonable approach is to try to guess what $\phi$ must be. Once you have a candidate function, you can rigorously prove that $S$ satisfies $S(z) = z\phi(S(z))$.
Here's how you guess:
Write $\phi(S) = a_0 + a_1S + a_2S^2 + \cdots,$ where $S$ is the formal power series $z + z^2 + 3z^3 + 11z^4 + 45z^5 + \cdots$. Now we can take advantage of the fact that $S = zT$ as a formal power series to write this as $\phi(S) = a_0 + Q_0z$, where $Q_0$ is a formal power series. But $\phi(S) = S/z = 1 + z + 3z^2 + 11z^3 + \cdots$ so we must have $a_0 = 1$ and $Q_0 = z + 3z^2 + 11z^3 + \cdots.$
Next we obtain $a_1$ in the same way. Write $\phi(S)-1 = a_1S + z^2Q_1(S)$. We also have $\phi(S) - 1 = z + 3z^2 + 11z^3 + \cdots$. Now we have $a_1 = 1$ and $Q_1(S) = 1 + 2z + 7z^3 + 28z^4 + \cdots$. Continuing in this way (you will have to compute higher powers of $S$ as you continue) you can find $a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$. Once you calculate these values, you can guess a formula for $a_n$ (I promise you'll see the pattern).
At this point we haven't proved anything (we have only calculated 5 coefficients), but once you know what function to try for $\phi$, I think you will have no problem verifying that $S$ and $\phi$ satisfy the identity.
EDIT: It looks like you derived the formula for the power series. There are two ways to proceed from here. If you are comfortable with the machinery of formal power series, simply observe that $\phi(S) = 1 + S/(1-2S)$. Then prove that $S$ satisfies the equation.
If you do not have the lemmas to make that rigorous, you can first prove the identity $$S = z + S^2 + S^3 + S^4 + \cdots.$$ This is Flajolet's formula, but you can also derive it combinatorially.
Then substitute the identity into itself once: $$S = z + (z + S^2 + S^3 + \cdots)S + S^3 + S^4 + \cdots = z + zS + 2S^3 + 2S^4 + \cdots.$$ Then substitute again: $$S = z + zS + 2S^2(z + S^2 + S^3 + \cdots) + 2S^4 + \cdots = z + zS + 2zS^2 + 4S^4 + \cdots.$$ Continue for $n$ steps. Conclude that $[z^n]S(z) = [z^n]z\phi(S(z))$. Therefore the power series are equal.
You can formalize this as a proof by induction.

Thanks for your answer, I computed $\phi$ as you suggested (see my edit), but I do not see how to formally show the desired identity.

Observe that $\phi(S) = 1 + S/(1-2S)$. Then prove that $S$ satisfies the equation.
If you do not have the lemmas to make that rigorous, you can first prove the identity $S = z + S^2 + S^3 + S^4 + ...$ (this is Flajolet's formula or you can derive it combinatorially). Then substitute the identity into itself once: $S = z + (z + S^2 + S^3 + ...)S + S^3 + S^4 + ... = z + zS + 2S^3 + 2S^4 + ...$. Then substitute again: $S = z + zS + 2S^2(z + S^2 + S^3 + ...) + 2S^4 + ...$. Continue for $n$ steps. Conclude that $[z^n]S(z) = [z^n]z\phi(S(z))$. Then note that $n$ is arbitrary.
